# Prove that if a function $f$ has an improper integral at an interval $I$ than it has an improper integral in any sub-interval of $I$

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

I want to prove/disprove the following claim: let $f: [a, b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. If $\int _a ^b f(x) dx$ converges then $c > a \implies \int _c ^b f(x) dx$ converges. ($b$ could be $\infty$)

It’s a claim that’s used in my professor's solutions, but I don’t know why it’s true. Don’t we have to prove that $\int _a ^c f(x) dx$ is a proper/convergent integral before making this claim?

Comment: Not necessarily

Comment: Usually convergence and value of improper integrals is defined as $\int_{a}^{b} f = lim_{c\to b} \int_{a}^{c} f$ if it exists, so it is almost tautological - are you using a different definition?

Comment: I'm using this definition, with some conditions that have to be met and with $b^-$ instead of $b$. How can we derive the claim from it?

Comment: Sure, since $\int_{c}^{b'} f = \int_{a}^{b'} f - \int_{a}^{c} f$ for any $c < b' < b$, so we can just take the limit $b' \to b$ which definitely exists for the right hand side

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I forgot that one of the conditions for $\int_a ^b f(x)dx$ to converge is that $\int _a ^c f(x)dx$ has to be proper for all $a < c < b$.